# Make an image behind an image be clickable

Tags: html, css, image

I'm hoping that there's a way to make an image that is stacked underneath another image be clickable while the front image is not.

The front image is a semi-transparent png (think of a watermark or similar). The image behind is linked to an action. (This is not exactly what it does, so please no off-topic comments about this being a poor way to watermark... I know that!)

However if the image is in front the action will not ever be triggered, as the front image is 'blocking' the click.

Answer (score 5):

Some code would be beneficial but it sounds like you need

```
pointer-events:none
```

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse events, the value none instructs the mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.

Support however (foot of reference page) is good except for IE which is 11+

Also: [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Comment: beat me by 10 seconds :)